# plot(p) and plot(ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(p))) don't seem to give same output when plot background is transparent

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following R ggplot code:

```html
require(ggplot2)
require(ggthemes)

df <- data.frame(x=1:10, y=5*(1:10))

p <- ggplot(df, aes(x,y)) +
   geom_point() +
   theme_few() +
   theme(plot.background = element_rect(fill='transparent', colour=NA), legend.position='top')

pdf('test.pdf', width=5, height=2)

plot(p)

plot(ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(p)))
```

But I do get two different figures:

[image]

[image]

I like the first figure (i.e without the background grid outside panel area). However, I also need to use ggplot_build() for some other processing. Could you please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could copy what `ggplot2::print.ggplot` does more directly. This seems to work.

```
pdf('test.pdf', width=5, height=2)

plot(p)

grid::grid.newpage()
grid::grid.draw(ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(p)))

dev.off()
```

Comment: Thanks @MrFlick. Your suggestion works. Only thing is that I now get message "null device 1". Commenting dev.off() vanished the message but still solves the provlem. Do we really need it? Anyway, thanks a lot for your quick reply.

Comment: The message is normal and expected. Anytime you do `pdf()`, that should be followed at some point by `dev.off()` to close the document.

Comment: I need another help. In my actual plot I have an inset picture that I create using viewport. Could you please suggest how to apply viewport as grid.draw does not take a viewport parameter?

Comment: I could solve the viewport issue. It seems straightforward. `grid.newpage()
grid.draw(ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(p)))
pushViewport(viewport(height=0.5, width=0.5, x=0.75, y=0.75))
grid.draw(ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(p)))`

Comment: The most important thing I learnt is that if you are using grid.draw you must do the conversion `ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(p))` instead of directly passing `p` to `grid.draw()` even when you do not need to change anything in the ggplot output `p`.

Comment: I was running into the same problem, awesome solution. Do you possibly have an explanation for this behaviour?