# Combining two grobs , one of them created using grid.draw

Tags: r, ggplot2, gridview, visualization, grob

I am trying to combine two graphical objects (`grob`) to a single plot - one of them created with "standard `ggplot()`" call, the other using `grid.draw()` on a `ggplot_gtable` object ([based on this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48066550/7941188)).

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)
library(gridExtra)

plot_gtable <- function(x) {
  grid::grid.draw(ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(x)))
}

plot1 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt)) + geom_point()
plot2 <- plot_gtable(ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg)) + geom_dotplot())

grid.arrange(plot1, plot2)
```

> Error in gList(structure(list(wrapvp = structure(list(x = structure(0.5, class = "unit", valid.unit = 0L, unit = "npc"), : only  'grobs' allowed in "gList"

<sup>Created on 2018-12-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Apparently, calling `grid.draw` results in `NULL` object, not a `grob`, which seems to be the reason why `grid.arrange()` fails in this case.

I tried with and without calling `grid::grid.newpage` first.

I tried using `grid::viewport` and `gridExtra::arrangeGrob` and `ggpubr::ggarrange` and `cowplot::plot_grid` and also `patchwork` package, all to no avail.

How can I create a combined plot with those objects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When combining plots and/or grobs using `grid.arrange` you want to use the actual object rather than trying to plot it. This is why `plot2` is `NULL` as it is drawn rather than returned, and so can't be combined. So don't draw it before combining the plots.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

# example ggplot
plot1 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt)) + geom_point()
# example gtable
plot2 <- ggplotGrob(plot1)

grid.arrange(plot1, plot2)
```

Comment: Thanks many times. As you noticed - I am just starting to get my head around those different objects and when you should use what. This was super helpful for me to understand a bit more here :)